# Why microsoft decides to disable type inference doesn't work on static in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

This question should be slightly different that the other question.

Type inference does not work for static variables.

```
Static lastAccessed = Now.AddDays(-1)
```

Simple code.

LastAccessed type should be date.

Tada it's object.

Why?

Obviously `Dim lastAccessed = Now.AddDays(-1)` would work just fine.

Why?

Note: I am well aware that I am not use the as clause. I deliberately don't do that because that's what type inference is for. The compiler can clearly see that the variable must of of type Date even without the as clause.

I am also aware that this may just be design decissions. However, I wonder why microsoft make that kind of decissions? Obviously static variables can be infered just as any local variables

So the question is, whether we uses dim or static, we know that the type can be infered  by the compiler at compile time.

So why does microsoft decides not to allow inference for static variables?

This question barely touches the issue. It's not even clear in the question that the asker uses static variables given that he uses dim. Still the answers there do not address why the design is that way.
[VB.NET and type inference using "Dim"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339397/vb-net-and-type-inference-using-dim?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: [Local Type Inference (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/variables/local-type-inference) seems to say to me that `Static` variables don't count as local variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VB.NET and type inference using "Dim"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339397/vb-net-and-type-inference-using-dim)

Comment: And do you have Option Strict **On**? It won't help, other than preventing that code from compiling.

Comment: Type inference exists to support the use of anonymous types in LINQ. It gets used far more widely than that but that's it's reason for existing. I would guess that type inference is not supported beyond non-static local variables because anonymous types are not supported in those contexts.

Comment: Let's also not forget that `Static` variables in VB are just syntactic sugar. They are actually fields that can only be accessed in one method and only get initialised the first time that method is called.

Comment: I vaguely recall that Eric Lippert discussed this same question in the context of C#, and it has something to do with what information is available to the compiler at the time it does a pass over the module context.

Comment: The other questions do not completely answer my questions. Or perhaps I should modify this question to why microsoft decide that static variables do not have inferences on

Answer (score 4):

Eric Lippert talks about why this doesn't work for the C# compiler in a blog post from eleven years ago: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields/

There's much more subtlety to type inference on a module-level (which `Static` variables are, functionally) than it might appear.  Trying to infer types at a module level potentially introduces a bunch of headaches (including the possibility of cycles that can't be resolved).  While it's true that it wouldn't be an issue for the simplest cases, the compiler developers need to worry about the complicated cases.

I would assume that the reasoning for C# also applies to VB.

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Comment: I'll note that there are actually two places where the duplication could be avoided: In the declaration (via var) or in the constructor (via target-typed `new`).  The latter does not suffer from the issues Eric describes.  See [the Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/100) for the current status of this proposal.  The down-side of target-typed `new` is that it cannot be used to avoid explicit declarations in factory calls and the like...but the value of removing duplication is much higher in the specific case of constructors.

Answer (score 1):

From
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/variables/local-type-inference
(emphasis mine):

> Type inference can be used **only for non-static local variables**; it cannot be used to determine the type of class fields, properties, or functions.

and

> Similarly, local type inference **does not apply to procedure level variables declared as Static**.

Seems like a design decision by Microsoft.
I guess they assumed the benefits would be the greatest in this typical idiom where a local variable is initialized, and never re-assigned.

```
Function DoSomething(value As Integer) As Integer
    Dim foo = New Foo(value)
    foo.DoProcess()
    Return foo.EndResult
End Function
```

(Though one might argue this function violates dependency inversion principle.)

As for static variables, those are typically more subject to being 'stateful',
so it makes sense to always specify its type explicitly. Obviously, there is no problem when initializer and subsequent assignments share the same type (e.g. Integer). It's different when the static variable can be assigned different implementations of the same interface.

```
Function DoSomething(value As Integer) As Integer
    Static foo As IFoo = New DefaultFooImplementation()
    If value <> 0 Then   ' else stick to the previous foo
        foo = FooFactory.Create(value)
    End If
    foo.DoProcess()
    Return foo.EndResult
End Function
```

Notice you cannot remove `As IFoo` here, even if the compiler would allow it.

You may argue that the same is possible for non-static local variables.

```
Function DoSomething(value As Integer) As Integer
    Dim foo As IFoo = New FirstFooImplementation()
    foo.DoProcess()
    Dim result1 As Integer = foo.EndResult
    foo = New SecondFooImplementation()
    foo.DoProcess()
    Dim result2 As Integer = foo.EndResult
    Return result1 + result2
End Function
```

But honestly, reusing a variable like that should be considered bad practice. I can imagine Microsoft refuses to stimulate that.

I admit it's not black and white between locals and statics.
It's still up to the developer to judge whether or not type inference is appropriate in any given case.

Comment: I would be glad if you explain more. It seems that your answer is correct. However, can you explain why static variables should alsways have explicit type given that we can infer on compile time the type easily?

Comment: @user4951 I edited my answer, added an example. But I guess Eric Lippert's article makes a much stronger point.